# Сбалансированное многопутевое распределение данных по сериям(алогоритм)

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка

Правильный ли алгоритм это для сбалансированной сортировки слиянием?(
имеем последовательсность чисел 1 -8 3 7 4 11 -0 13 -2 6

1. считываем первые 4 числа

   - a1 < a2 < a3 < a4? нет [],[],[],[];
   - a1 < a2 < a3? нет [],[],[],[];
   - a1 < a2? нет [],[],[],[];
   - [1'],[],[],[];
   - a2 < a3 < a4? нет [1'],[],[],[];
   - a2 < a3? нет [1'],[],[],[];
   - [1'],[-8'],[],[];
   - a3 < a4? да [1'],[-8'],[3,7'],[];
2. Следующие 4 числа

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так - делением на примерно пополам, пока не будут получаться пары чисел. Потом процесс идет обратно. Сбалансированность выражается в том, что размеры групп отличаются не более чем на 1. Слияние выполняется путем поочередного взятия первых двух чисел из двух групп, их сравнения и передачи в результирующее множество меньшего из чисел.

```
             1   -8    3    7    4   11    0   13   -2    6

         1   -8    3    7    4     |     11    0   13   -2    6
                                   |                    |
     1   -8    3   |    7    4     |     11    0   13   |    -2    6
                   |               |
 1   -8   |    3   |    4    7     |     11    0   |   13    |   -2    6
          |        |               |               |         |
-8    1   |    3   |    4    7     |      0   11   |   13    |   -2    6
                   |               |                    |
    -8    1    3   |    4    7     |      0   11   13   |    -2    6
                                   |
         -8    1    3   4    7     |     -2    0    6   11   13 

            -8   -2    0    1    3    4    6    7   11   13
```

Comment: как мы узнаем где половина, если работаем txt файлом и ifstream?

Comment: @dahbka В условии этого не было. Но, думаю, например так - если файл позволяет все запихнуть в память, то в памяти. Если нет - то делим, например, все четные записи в один файл, нечетные - во второй. И рекурсивно работаем с половинками, а потом сливаем их - уж сливать-то как раз из файлов очень легко..

Comment: спасибо, а какое практическое применение сбалансированной сортировки?

Comment: Сортировать :) У него гарантированная производительность `O(N*log N)`, при этом позволяет работать с файлами.